# What do the eigenvalues of a random element of $\mathbb Z_\ell[\Gamma]$ look like?

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, random-matrices, profinite-groups

Let $\Gamma = \varprojlim \Gamma_n$ be a profinite group with $\Gamma_n$ finite quotients. For concreteness, let us fix $\Gamma_n = \operatorname{PGL}_2(\mathbb Z/\ell^n)$ so $\Gamma = \operatorname{PGL}_2(\mathbb Z_\ell)$.

Let $R = \mathbb Z_\ell[[\Gamma]]$ be the completed group algebra and consider its action on itself. If we pick a random element $\gamma \in R$, what does the distribution of its eigenvalues look like?

More precisely, call the image of $\gamma$ in $R_n = \mathbb Z_\ell[\Gamma_n]$ as $\gamma_n$. Now $\gamma_n$ acts linearly on the finite free $\mathbb Z_\ell$-module $R_n$ and let its set of eigenvalues be $S_n$. Can we say anything about the distribution of $S_n$ as $n\to \infty$?

For a simpler situation, we can consider $\Gamma = \mathbb Z_\ell$ and then $R \cong \mathbb Z_\ell[[t]]$ and if $\gamma = f(t)$, then $\gamma_n$ will have eigenvalues $f(\zeta_{\ell^n}^i-1)$ for $i=1,\dots, n$ (unless I made a mistake in the computation).

I am not even sure what we can say about this set as $n\to \infty$.